Connection reset issue while adding column on a large hbase table using Phoenix
Recently, we got into an unique issue while adding a column to a large table. The alter table statement is like this:
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD IF NOT EXISTS colfamily.CITYID BIGINT;
This has actually added the column, but produces an error message, which eventually marked the job which is responsible to call this statement.
Here is the error snippet:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD IF NOT EXISTS colfamily.CITYID BIGINT": java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

As I am using Cloudera, I have asked for a solution. They suggested to disable major compaction on the table and run that alter statement.
OR
Run the major compaction just before the alter.
The challenege here is, I can't disable the major compaction, that can impact read & write.
And running major compaction on the large table will go for a 5-6 Hrs time to finish and I have to wait till then to run the alter and miss the window when the column is actually scheduled to be added.
Looking for suggestions to deal with this situation.
--Thanks
As mentioned above I have triggered the major compaction just before running the ALTER. But my automation process will be violated if I do this manual work in Prod
